# Having trouble inserting into mysql database via php with php variables? Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, database, variables, insert

Register.php

```
<?php

include("db.php");
if (isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password']) && isset($_POST['name']) &&  isset($_POST['password2']) && isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['address']) && isset($_POST['city']) && isset($_POST['state']))

{
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost", "useradmin", "FNEpsTa6qvmRjBBf", "userdata") or die("failed to connect");
    //Prevent SQL injections
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $city = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['city']);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    $password2 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password2']);

    //Get MD5 hash of password
    $password = md5($_POST['password']);
    $query="SELECT email FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'";
    $query2="INSERT INTO users (name, email, address, city, state, password) VALUES ('$name', '$email', '$address', '$city', '$state', '$password');";
    //Check to see if email exists
    $sql = mysqli_query($con, $query);
    $rows=(mysqli_num_rows($sql));
    if($rows>0)
    {
        die ("email taken.");
    }
    if($password<>$password2)
    {
        die ("passwords do not match");
    }

    $sql = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
    if($sql)
        header(location:welcome.php);

}
?>

<html></html>
<center>
<form action="register.php" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td>Name: </td><td><input name="name" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Email:</td><td> <input name="email" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Address: </td><td><input name="address" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>City: </td><td><input name="city" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>State: </td><td><select name="State"> 
<option value="" selected="selected">Select a State</option> 
<option value="AL">Alabama</option> 
<option value="AK">Alaska</option> 
<option value="AZ">Arizona</option> 
<option value="AR">Arkansas</option> 
<option value="CA">California</option> 
<option value="CO">Colorado</option> 
<option value="CT">Connecticut</option> 
<option value="DE">Delaware</option> 
<option value="DC">District Of Columbia</option> 
<option value="FL">Florida</option> 
<option value="GA">Georgia</option> 
<option value="HI">Hawaii</option> 
<option value="ID">Idaho</option> 
<option value="IL">Illinois</option> 
<option value="IN">Indiana</option> 
<option value="IA">Iowa</option> 
<option value="KS">Kansas</option> 
<option value="KY">Kentucky</option> 
<option value="LA">Louisiana</option> 
<option value="ME">Maine</option> 
<option value="MD">Maryland</option> 
<option value="MA">Massachusetts</option> 
<option value="MI">Michigan</option> 
<option value="MN">Minnesota</option> 
<option value="MS">Mississippi</option> 
<option value="MO">Missouri</option> 
<option value="MT">Montana</option> 
<option value="NE">Nebraska</option> 
<option value="NV">Nevada</option> 
<option value="NH">New Hampshire</option> 
<option value="NJ">New Jersey</option> 
<option value="NM">New Mexico</option> 
<option value="NY">New York</option> 
<option value="NC">North Carolina</option> 
<option value="ND">North Dakota</option> 
<option value="OH">Ohio</option> 
<option value="OK">Oklahoma</option> 
<option value="OR">Oregon</option> 
<option value="PA">Pennsylvania</option> 
<option value="RI">Rhode Island</option> 
<option value="SC">South Carolina</option> 
<option value="SD">South Dakota</option> 
<option value="TN">Tennessee</option> 
<option value="TX">Texas</option> 
<option value="UT">Utah</option> 
<option value="VT">Vermont</option> 
<option value="VA">Virginia</option> 
<option value="WA">Washington</option> 
<option value="WV">West Virginia</option> 
<option value="WI">Wisconsin</option> 
<option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select></td></tr>
<tr><td>Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="password" /></td></tr>
<tr><td>Confirm Password: </td><td><input type="password" name="password2" /></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit" /></td></tr>
</table>
</form></center>
```

page runs without errors but does not show up in database
I enter the data and hit submit, which returns me to the page without errors, but the information is never inserted into my database. Also the database connection is good as I've checked it. But below is an export of the database.

```
CREATE DATABASE userdata;
USE userdata;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `City` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `State` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
  `Email` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `Password` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Email`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Password` (`Password`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

created the user with that password in php myadmin so I know it is good.

Comment: here changed some code it helped but now I'm getting undefined index for state. Here is the changed code

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using the mysqli extension, not mysql, you must use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` rather than `mysql_real_escape_string()`.

But you really should be using prepared statements instead of interpolating variables into the query. Then you don't have to worry about escaping the values at all. This is one of the main benefits of using mysqli or PDO rather than mysql.

Comment: will change the function, I wouldn't know how to go about using prepared statements though. Could you send me a link for that in manual?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
if ($con->connect_error) {
die('Connect Error (' . $con->connect_errno . ') '
        . $con->connect_error);
}
```

after you connecting to DB. Also I would add

```
$sql = mysqli_query($con, $query2);
if($sql) {
    header(location:welcome.php);
} else {
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}
```

to see possible errors of your quesries.

Comment: added both and still seeing no errors, still not showing up in the database either though